# How to add newlines between tow @imported sass files?

Tags: css, sass, yeoman

My main.scss file is as:

```
@import "components/variables.scss"; // This file contains all font variables etc  

@import "components/global.scss"; // This file contains global styles to be applied 

@import "components/header.scss"; // All header and top menu navigation

@import "components/bslider.scss"; // The main middle slider that have whole content of webside as slides.
```

I have added newlines after each @import statement but when the output is generated there is no space in between css of individual files. The output is like this:

```
* {
    font-size: 14px;
}
/*global css finishes*/
/*header css starts*/
header {
    position: absolute;
}
```

But I want newlines like this:

```
* {
    font-size: 14px;
}
/*global css finishes*/


/*header css starts*/
header {
    position: absolute;
}
```

I am using yeoman webapp generator to convert sass into css. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used yeoman , but you can change the style of the css that is output

```
sass --watch yourfile.scss:style.css --style expanded
```

You can read more on SASS styles here:

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style

Comment: I am already getting sass output as expanded. But this doesn't preserve newlines from sass.